# What should the "share" subdirectory contain?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, libraries

When one has installed a library and look at what its repository contain, he may find something like that:

repo/

- bin/
- lib/
- share/

What the "share" repository should contain in general?
Are there other types of subdirectories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "share" word is used because what is under /usr/share is platform independent, and can be shared among several machines across a network filesystem. Therefore this is the place for manuals, documentations, examples etc.

[RTFM](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/fhs.html)